# How to clear the screen of NANO-Editor , to open a NEW textfile?

Tags: linux, editor, nano

How to clear the screen of NANO-Editor , to open a NEW textfile ?

A file is loaded.

When i read a new file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> the file is INSERTED in the actual file.

What i want is to unload and clear the screen first. a empy nano.

Then read a NEW file IN !!!

Thats all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple options you can use:

## Clean the content of the "existing" file (within nano):

Go to the start of the file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>

Mark the text: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>

Go to the end of the file (setting the mark): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Cut the text: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Insert the new file/content using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

## Clean the content of the "existing" file (prior to open nano):

If you have content already in a file you want to open, you can execute this command:

```
> file-name && nano file-name
```

The <kbd>></kbd> will clean your file prior to open it. and then you can proceed to import the new content.

Hope one of above options works for you :)